# Can I run a jenkinsfile from an already made freestyle project?

Tags: bash, docker, jenkins-pipeline, ubuntu-18.04

I am currently making a jenkins project on an EC2 instance using ubuntu and have learned about jenkinsfiles. My already made pipeline to automatically detect changes to a github repo is the one I want to make run the jenkinsfile which as of now has only echo commands. Is this possible? I cannot seem to find much at all about this.

I have tried looking it up on youtube and google to no avail. Youtube videos show people creating new pipelines but I am wondering if its at all possible to do it on an already made freestyle project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do that. When you create a new job you have to chose if it's a pipeline or not. There may be some workaround to run a jenkinsfile from some magic shell script, but that's already sounds making more problems than how many it solves.

[image]